# Confusing PermMask values in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, jslink

I came across the **PermMask** values while using *JSLink* in SharePoint Online for checking permissions of user from the `ctx.CurrentItem.PermMask`

The values for different permissions aren't matching with the Microsoft's documentation, any idea what these values represent? or they have to be converted into some other format? I haven't come across these values expect for the Admin permission whose value is 0x7fffffffffffffff

0x1b03c431aef - Edit

---

0xb008431041  - View Only

---

0x1b03c4312ef - Contribute

---

0x1b03c5f1bff - Design

---

0x7fffffffffffffff - Admin

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sum of Permissions.

For example:

View Only includes below permissions.

```
ViewListItems = 1
ViewVersions = 64
CreateAlerts = 549755813888
ViewFormPages = 4096
CreateSSCSite = 4194304
ViewPages = 131072
BrowseUserInfo = 134217728
UseRemoteAPIs = 137438953472
UseClientIntegration = 68719476736
Open = 65536
```

The sum is 756052856897=0xb008431041

Answer (score 2):

`webPermMasks` are TWO 32-bit integers indicating which permissions a user has.

Each bit represents a permission.

```
(_spPageContextInfo.webPermMasks.High).toString(2)
(_spPageContextInfo.webPermMasks.Low).toString(2)
```

Displays the bits

#### High & Low

In the good old days computer worked with 8 bits, which someone named a Byte.
With 8 bits (8 permissions) you can only count from 0 to 255

**So to store a larger number of 16 bits (0- 32768) on an 8-bit CPU you need 2 Bytes.**

We called these the **High-Byte** and the **Low-Byte**

[image]

#### SharePoint has 37 types of permissions

Present computers have evolved from CPUs that can handle 8-bits to 16-bits to **32-bits**

Currently SharePoint has **37** different Security permissions.. 
which do not fit in those **32 bits**

Like so many moons ago you **need TWO 32-bit values to encode Permissions**
Which some Microsoft engineer with common sense named the **High** and **Low** value

The SP.js library (available standard on most pages) has the information on which Permission is which **bit number**

Run this in the developer console:

```
for (var permLevelName in SP.PermissionKind.prototype) {
    if (SP.PermissionKind.hasOwnProperty(permLevelName)) {
        var permLevel = SP.PermissionKind.parse(permLevelName);
           console.info(permLevelName,permLevel);
        }
    }
}
```

Note `permLevel` is **not** the **value**, it is the **bit-number**

`SP.PermissionKind.openItems` is bit-number **6** and thus value **2^6**

If you **add up** all the values you get the **High order** and **Low order** integer values for Permissions.

Note `permLevel` for `SP.PermissionKind.manageAlerts` is the **39th bit**

This is in the High order integer, so the value is **2^(39-31)**

#### webPermMasks

```
   _spPageContextInfo.webPermMasks.Low
   _spPageContextInfo.webPermMasks.High
```

Gives you **64 bits in TWO 32 bit Integers** (with 37 permissions only a few are used in the High order)

**indicating what *Permissions* the *Current User* has on the *Current Page***

### All PermissionKinds (SP.PermissionsKnd.[name])

Note: This is the **bit-number**, not the value!

To check if someone has permissions, 
You have to calculate the (summed) value then **binary** check against the High and Low order integers.

```
    viewListItems: 1
    addListItems: 2
    editListItems: 3
    deleteListItems: 4
    approveItems: 5
    openItems: 6
    viewVersions: 7
    deleteVersions: 8
    cancelCheckout: 9
    managePersonalViews: 10
    manageLists: 12
    viewFormPages: 13
    anonymousSearchAccessList: 14
    open: 17
    viewPages: 18
    addAndCustomizePages: 19
    applyThemeAndBorder: 20
    applyStyleSheets: 21
    viewUsageData: 22
    createSSCSite: 23
    manageSubwebs: 24
    createGroups: 25
    managePermissions: 26
    browseDirectories: 27
    browseUserInfo: 28
    addDelPrivateWebParts: 29
    updatePersonalWebParts: 30
    manageWeb: 31
    anonymousSearchAccessWebLists: 32
    useClientIntegration: 37
    useRemoteAPIs: 38
    manageAlerts: 39
    createAlerts: 40
    editMyUserInfo: 41
    enumeratePermissions: 63
```

#### Use in script

The SP library supplies a function to check for individual levels:

```
  SP.PageContextInfo.get_webPermMasks().has( [bitnumber] );

  SP.PageContextInfo.get_webPermMasks().has( SP.PermissionKind.enumeratePermissions );
```

#### Using unused space (tales of the past)

Only a handfull of bits in the High Order integer are used by SharePoint.

Yet the database stores all 32 bits...

When we still built SharePoint Back End stuff we would use those unused bits for our own Permission scheme.

The free trials we let everyone install was actually the full blown product.
And when they bought the Licensed Product.. all it did was flip one bit in the database.

J1 iSPT